# Email Spam Filtering at the Code Level in Java

Tags: java, email, email-spam, spam-prevention

I'm writing code to download email from various servers, some of which are outside of my control. I'd like to be able to filter out spam at the code level since I can't always rely on the servers to do it effectively. What resources in Java are available to help with this? What is a good approach to take in order to minimize the amount of spam I need to wade through?

Currently I am just using the JavaMail API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From JavaMail 3rd Party Products.

> jASEN is a pure Java Anti Spam ENgine
>   combining bayesian-like scanning with
>   intelligent email inspection and
>   classification. jASEN is best suited
>   to developers wishing to integrate
>   anti-spam services into an existing
>   server based Java email application,
>   but can be used for client
>   applications. Available at:
>   http://www.jasen.org

More JavaMail 3rd Party Products here: http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/Third_Party.html

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like [Jasen](http://www.jasen.org/) may be of use.